# Cannot find module "/operator/share.js" in package rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6

Tags: angular

- Angular version: 2
- Editor: Webstorm

When I start my angular-2 by `npm start` and refresh the App page in the browser, I get the following errors:

[image]

Now, if i open one of the mentioned URL in above errors such as (`https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6/operator/share.js`) in a new tab then I get the following **error**:

> ```
> Cannot find module "/operator/share.js" in package rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6
> ```

But if I refresh the new tab again, get the body of its codes successfully but anyway I still get above errors in my App webpage:

```
"use strict";
var multicast_1 = require('./multicast');
var Subject_1 = require('../Subject');
function shareSubjectFactory() {
    return new Subject_1.Subject();
}
/**
 * Returns a new Observable that multicasts (shares) the original Observable. As long as there is at least one
 * Subscriber this Observable will be subscribed and emitting data. When all subscribers have unsubscribed it will
 * unsubscribe from the source Observable. Because the Observable is multicasting it makes the stream `hot`.
 * This is an alias for .publish().refCount().
 *
 * <img src="./img/share.png" width="100%">
 *
 * @return {Observable<T>} an Observable that upon connection causes the source Observable to emit items to its Observers
 * @method share
 * @owner Observable
 */
function share() {
    return multicast_1.multicast.call(this, shareSubjectFactory).refCount();
}
exports.share = share;
;
//# sourceMappingURL=share.js.map
```

- **What is the reason of above behavior?**
  Why first time I request the js file it return `Cannot find module....` but after a refresh I get its code body?
- **How can I solve the above problem?**

Comment: Why are you still using Angular 2 and a beta version of RxJS?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, Because I am a beginner and I'm learning Angular by a learning project. I downloaded its base project from Github and I'm writing the codes step by step by which  the teacher learn in the video. Every things was OK and I wrote several mini sample components and directives in this project. But now when I refresh the page I get these errors and can not find the reason still.

Answer (score 0):

*I found the fix:*

In `settingjs.config.js` file instead of

```
'rxjs': 'https://npmcdn.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6',
```

I used:

```
'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
```